# google map not showing up on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The Google map is not showing up on the php version of my website page. Please help. Here is the webpage and the source code.

```
<section class="meteor-google-map fullwidth block" style="height: 450px; border: solid transparent; border-width: 1px 0; margin-bottom: 4em;">
<div class="" style="height: 450px; border: solid transparent; border-width: 1px 0; margin-bottom: 4em;">
<span class="map-data hidden">{"latlong":"44.99746,-91.72712","type":"ROADMAP","zoom":16,"title":"Our Headquarters","link":"","tooltip":"","fullscreen":true}</span>
<div class="infobox-content hidden">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
</div><!-- .meteor-google-map -->
</section>
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? I have only seen google maps embedded with an iframe and usually requires API keys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: From a template that was downloaded from themeforest.net

Comment: it works in an html version of the page but when switched to php it does not show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using that content inside your SPAN TAG, you can use this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2821.3526561090844!2d-91.72712!3d44.997460000000004!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNDTCsDU5JzUwLjkiTiA5McKwNDMnMzcuNiJX!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1415155466768" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I hope thats what you are looking for

Comment: Not so much. The map just shows up in the left had side of the page off center and not full screen width.

Comment: <section class="meteor-google-map fullwidth block" style="height: 450px; border: solid transparent; border-width: 1px 0; margin-bottom: 4em;">
  <div class="" style="height: 450px; border: solid transparent; border-width: 1px 0; margin-bottom: 4em;">
    <span class="map-data hidden">{"latlong":"44.89630,-91.92925","type":"ROADMAP","zoom":16,"title":"Our Headquarters","link":"","tooltip":"","fullscreen":true}     </span>
    <div class="infobox-content hidden">
      <p>Perfection Painting Shop Location.</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .meteor-google-map -->
    </section>

Comment: here is a link to the php page and the html page for reference. [link](http://www.menomoniepainting.com/contact.php) and [link](http://www.menomoniepainting.com/contact.php)

Comment: can you help with this? The actual map location lat and long is 44.89630 (lat) and -91.92925 (long)

Comment: Just use the code That I gave to you, erase all the code inside **<span class="map-data hidden">** and place my code INSIDE this tag: **<span class="map-data hidden">** . Remove that Hidden class and give all style that you want to that Iframe, you can put 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your page sources, your .php version is not loading half the scripts in the header that your.html version is. I think this is probably related.